# How to display volume bar in starting from lowest price in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to add custom volume bars with some extra MA, but I can't scale it so that it starts from just bellow lowest price.  I've tried many different options but always the same.  I found answer for this issue but it doesn't work (still starts from 0)

```
// This shows an example of how to place values at the bottom of the main chart and scale with chart
//@version=5
indicator("FRM Volume Scale v1.0", "Scaler", true, format = format.volume, scale =  scale.none)

// Inputs
scalePercentage = input.int(30, "Vertical %", step = 10, maxval = 100)
lookBack = input.int(100, "Last Bars to Look", minval = 2, step = 20)

scaleFactor = 100 / scalePercentage
plot(volume, color = color.orange, title="Volume", style=plot.style_columns, transp=0) 
limit = ta.highest(volume, lookBack)
plot(limit * scaleFactor, "High", #00000000)
```

I've was able to adjust scale to display only on bottom part of the chart, but to shift it up I wasn't able (last plot just draws a line, not changing bottom part)
My current code is following:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Volume Bar", "Scaler", true, format = format.volume, scale =  scale.none)
    
// Inputs
scalePercentage = input.int(30, "Vertical %", step = 10, maxval = 100)
lookBack = input.int(100, "Last Bars to Look", minval = 2, step = 20)
    
scaleFactor = 100 / scalePercentage
c_off_vol = volume * ta.highest(high, lookBack) / ta.highest(volume, lookBack) + ta.lowest(low, lookBack) / scaleFactor
plot(i_vol_on ? c_off_vol / scaleFactor : na, "Volume", color= open < close ? color.new(color.green, 50) : color.new(color.red, 50), style=plot.style_columns)
```

regardless what I do for offset it still starts from 0

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to plot volume bars in the same chart as the candlesticks?

Comment: yes to save vertical space, and use other indicators rather in separate chart

Comment: Is there an issue with pinning the volume indicator to the left scale as the built-in volume indicator does by default?

Comment: No built-in volume indicator is good, I would just like to modify a bit, and add more SMA on to it so I would like to make it custom

Comment: No, I meant that you can pin your indicator to the left scale.

Comment: I'm doing without the scale, as I want to also plot emas on the price, so I need to normalize both

Comment: To be honest, the easiest way would be to have your EMAs as a separate indicator.